# Linkedin API: how to use my login credential in my access token

Tags: api, profile, linkedin-api, stay-logged-in

I'm building my website to pull out my own linkedin profile info. And it is working but when a visitor comes to the site, they will have to login to see my profile info displayed on my page. This should be a public website and I don't want visitors to log in to **their** linkedin account in order to see my public page.

Is there anyway to do this (so that visitors can see my info without having to be logged in) ? Thank you

NOTE: I'm using their REST API by the way.

Simple code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1091) (section #1, bullet point 3), it is not possible to share your profile information via the API without the user both authenticating your LinkedIn application that is pulling the info, and also the authenticated user then being connected to you in some way. From that document, "Each user must grant your application access to their LinkedIn network and they can only see data from their own LinkedIn network. For example, you cannot gather information about a LinkedIn member in one user's LinkedIn network and show that information to other users"

In short, the REST API is probably not the way to go to expose un-authenticate user's to your profile.  What you might want to do is use one of the plugins, such as the [Member Profile plugin](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1278).